# Help deciphering piece of guitar tablature

Tags: guitar, tablature

does anyone know exactly how this bit of tab is supposed to be played ? I understand the numbers of course but I've never seen this "W.C" or a circle around the notes, what does it mean ?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

[image: guitar tab excerpt with circled notation, "W.C" above]

Comment: Please update the post with the source of the score (title, composer, and link if possible). That context may help answer the question and be valuable for future askers.

Comment: If you know what unison bends are, that’s certainly what this is meant to be, but it’s notated poorly

Comment: Have you listened to the piece being played?

Comment: The 'bend' numbers are confusing. True, the fret number played doesn't change, but bends are shown in tab with the start fret, then the fret of the note bent up to. So the 1st example should show 12-14, 2nd 15-17, 3rd 17-19.

Answer (score 2):

Because the standard notation above the TAB shows two unison notes the most logical thing is to say the notes on the G string are meant to be bent up a whole step to match the pitch of the notes on the B string. This is not the way bends are typically written in TAB and I have never seen W.C. before. Bends are usually written with a curved upwards arrow and “half” or “whole” is written above the arrowhead to indicate how much to bend the note.

Comment: Yep - it's definitely a unison bend, just using a non-standard nomenclature.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that the circles around the numbers mean half notes (minims). Quarter notes would get no circle and a stem, eighth notes would get a stem and one flag, and so on.

No idea about W. C., though. I also wonder about the tuning of the guitar — if it is supposed to be standard tuning, then the tab does not match the score.

Comment: Tuning is a half step down :)

Comment: It’s just a guess but WC could be “wide choke” or “whole [step] choke”. Choke being British for bend. It’s a unison bend but notated in a way that is nonstandard and confusing.

Comment: @ToddWilcox, ah, that would explain the weird numbers on the 3rd string then. I haven't ever heard the term "choke", only "bend", so I was really confused (I actually thought that the score is probably wrong).

Comment: @ToddWilcoxchoke is not British for bend. A bend may well be choked, but the two are very different. The choke part of a bend is when the target pitch is reached, the note is choked - i.e. cut off short. Since two of these notes in the question are written as long notes, it's probably not going to be a choked bend.

Comment: Seems pointless making the tab show note values - they're written properly just above!